# Torrent tracker site on my PC

Tags: file-sharing, bittorrent, p2p

I really need to create a torrent tracker site today and its really damn important to me.
I've been lurking here for some time and you guys are really great.
I would love someone to hold my hand and guide me thru the process of installing the tracker software on my linux machine and set it up as a torrent tracker site that can be accessed by everyone(Which tracker soft is the best? Opentracker doesnt seem to work on my machine so lemme know any other alternatives).
I did lots of research on google but most of the software links and guides are outdated.
Thank you.

Comment: quite a few torrent clients run their own trackers - qbitorrent, which I use, has one as an advanced option. These days though, DHT makes trackers a LOT less important

Comment: @JourneymanGeek qbitorrent can't be used to create a torrent tracker site AFAIK , pls read the question again.

Comment: We don't do "suggest some software for XYZ" and especially "which software is best" type questions here. Also, instead of simply asking for complete tutorials, might make sense to actually try something and then ask here about how to proceed when you get stuck.